# AMD Radeon HD 7770 (Cape Verde XT) and AMDGPU PRO drivers

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

I've tried installing AMDGPU Pro linux drivers, and after the reboot, resolution gets messed up, and after trying to log in, it spits me out back to the login page again. After getting to the terminal and trying manually to start X, I get an error.

Card in question is Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X].

I've followed all the instructions from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx).

Do I need to downgrade to 14.04 to get the card working properly? I'm currently on 16.04.

I really need the drivers to run properly, since Android Virtual Device and Genymotion won't run at all.

Comment: I don't see your card on the supported devices list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMDGPU PRO drivers are in beta, and don't support the AMD Cape Verde cards yet.  (Note that the page you link to doesn't list the card.)

I can't find the link now but remember reading that support is planned for next year, and that it will require kernel version 4.8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, my best solution would be 14.04 with [this driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu+x86+64) ?

Comment: If you need the AMD proprietary driver, then 14.04 with fglrx (Crimson) for now is the supported solution. I managed to compile Crimson for 16.04 but not without issues: https://github.com/zwets/amd-opencl-patches (and this was only the OpenCL part, not the graphics).